# Android/JSoup - get value from tag

Tags: android, jsoup

I receive data from external device and save on mobile as text file. My problem is - I need to get value userID from that text file. Value is kept in tag. For example

```
<user>1234</user>
```

I'm trying to use JSoup to archieve this but I have some complications.

Here is my code :

```
public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            try {
                InputStream in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
                Date date = new Date();
                File root = new File("/sdcard/mente/" + user.getID() );
                if(!root.exists())
                root.mkdirs();
                String fileName = connectedDeviceSerialNumber + "_" + date + ".txt".replace(" ","_");
                file = new File(root,fileName);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int count;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                    for (byte b : bytes) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "CommunicationThread: " + sb.toString() );
                    if (sb.toString().contains("3C 65 6E 64 5F 72 61 77 3E 74 72 75 65 3C 2F 65 6E 64 5F 72 61 77 3E") && syncProgressDialog != null) {
                        syncProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
                Elements el = doc.select("user");
                String userId = el.attr("user");
                Log.e(TAG, "STR: " + userId );


                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2")));
                Log.e(TAG, "synchData1: ");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: What complications ?

Comment: Jsoup doesnt find any value with tag <user>. Log shows "STR + "" ";

Comment: Is that the only thing stored in your text file or some other values too ?

Comment: Others too like <date> , <deviceId> and some medical data

Comment: are you able to fetch those data ? Is there any error shown in logs ?

Comment: No error. I didnt try to catch other data - I need only userId

Comment: and is your text file getting stored properly or not.

Comment: Yes, it is :) I can view it correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156351/discussion-between-vivek-mishra-and-bartos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are not getting the text properly

**Instead**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
Elements el = doc.select("user");
String userId = el.attr("user");
```

**You should**

```
String userId = "";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
Elements el = doc.select("user"); // el is an ArrayList... not a single element...
if(!el.isEmpty()) {
    Element singleElement = el.get(0);
    if (singleElement.hasText()) {
        userId = singleElement.text(); // Don't read attr... but text()
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "tag <user> has no text");
    }
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "tag <user> not fould");
}
```

**EDIT**

I tested with a file with following format:

```
<user>1234</user>
<pass>1234</pass>
```

It works fine. You said is not working for you, so, maybe, `sb.toString()` does not contain the proper text (which you can log to confirm... `Log.e(TAG, "sb: " + sb.toString());` ) or it has a different format that I tested.... So, please, share an example of string that you are reading.

Comment: tag <user> not found so it looks like el is empty :/ But why ... I'm sure tag <user> is there.

Comment: I updated my answer... could you please double check

Comment: Terrific! Glad I could help